# Is there a generalization of universal algebra in which inequalities are permitted?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, category-theory, universal-algebra

In ordinary universal algebra, we consider only equational axioms like $$x + y = y + x, \qquad x + -x = 0.$$

There's a generalization of universal algebra in which quasi-equations are permitted, which are basically implications between finite conjunctions of equations. For example, the notion of a cancellative monoid can be axiomatized by quasi-equations; the left-cancellation law is
$$ax = ay \rightarrow x = y$$

It seems reasonable to consider a variant on this in which inequalities are also fair game. For example, to axiomatize integral domains, we might use an appropriate cancellation law:
$$a \neq 0 \wedge ax = ay \rightarrow x = y.$$

Alternatively, we could use a version of the null-factor law: $$ab = 0 \wedge a \neq 0 \rightarrow b = 0.$$

I envisage that the morphisms between models would be taken as injective homomorphisms. Such categories won't usually have products or a terminal object, though they'll often have an initial object and/or  coproducts.

Here's an example of how such categories might be useful.

> **Definition.** A *non-degenerate Peano structure* consists of a triple $(X,S,0)$ where $X$ is a set, $S :X \rightarrow X$ is an injective function, $0 \in X$ is an element, and $\forall x \in X(S(x) \neq 0)$ is assumed to hold.

The informal statement that every non-degenerate Peano structure contains a natural copy of $\mathbb{N}$ can be formally stated as "$\mathbb{N}$ is the initial non-degenerate Peano structure."

> **Question.** Can any interesting results be proved for category of models of "quasi-equations with negation", where the morphisms are taken to be injective homomorphisms?

Comment: I suspect that these categories generally won't be nice, since fields are axiomatizable by quasi-equations with negation. (Commutative unital ring axioms plus a unary function $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ satisfying $x\ne 0 \to x(x^{-1})=1$)

Comment: @jgon, yes, that's a good point. However, I'd probably call that a "pointed field", since it consists of a field together with a choice of value of $x^{-1}$. Following [meadow theory](https://meadowsite.wordpress.com/), we should probably define $0^{-1} = 0$. This makes no sense topologically, but algebraically it's the best option. And that way, we're not dealing with "pointed fields", but rather with bona-fide fields.

Comment: Oh yes, good point, sorry, that was my intent, but words to express that didn't end up on the page.

Comment: Allegories are a form of categories defined by inclusions rather than equations, moreover their variations are axiomatised by Horn clauses; so that might be something to look into for insight --see the standard text *Allegories, Categories* ;-)