# Is there a generalization of universal algebra that can express multi-valued functions?

Tags: logic, universal-algebra

Is there a generalization of universal algebra that can express multi-valued functions?

I've seen mentions of generalizations of universal algebra that [add conditionals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3020004/is-there-a-generalization-of-universal-algebra-in-which-inequalities-are-permitt) and have heard about generalizations that use $\le$ instead of $\approx$ (as a topic within order theory, I think). [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2818537/is-there-a-generalization-of-universal-algebras-that-allows-the-use-of-multiple) asks about extending universal algebra with multiple sorts.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4116644) to a question I asked a month ago defines a new quasi-operation $*$ that can be thought of as a superposition of $+$ and $\times$. [This comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4115344/is-it-possible-to-formulate-the-theory-of-rings-using-a-3-place-relation#comment8512283_4116644) on that answer specifically asks about a generalization of ordinary universal algebra.

Are there already-studied generalizations of universal algebra that can handle quasi-operations like $*$?

---

One example of a potential generalization might be replacing $\approx$ with $\subset$, examples below.

$$ a + b \subset a * b $$
$$ a \times b \subset a * b $$

This generalization might not be expressive enough though; it is just an example. Without the ability to insist on additional rules (such as requiring certain functions to be single-valued or requiring functions to be non-zero-valued), we always have an "empty structure" where the functions always return the empty set and a "full structure" where they always return the entire universe.

Comment: I think you should unaccept my answer, at least for now - I'm not an expert, and accepting an answer this early may deter others who know more from posting answers of their own.

Comment: Done. I usually accept early and sometimes move it around. Sounds like that's not cool so I'll stop doing it.

Comment: I mean, it's not *un*cool, it just diminishes your chances of receiving more answers. Ultimately it's totally fine and up to you, I just don't recommend it personally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert (indeed I'm the above-linked commenter), but let me make a quick observation which suggests that this topic is probably subsumed by the theory of partially-orderd algebras (which didn't occur to me at the time of my original comment).

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{F})$ is a "multivalued algebra," that is, $X$ is a set and $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of functions from Cartesian powers of $X$ to $\mathcal{P}_{\not=\emptyset}(X)$ (or $\mathcal{P}(X)$ if we want to allow partiality). This induces a collection of *singlevalued algebras* in the same signature as follows:

- We start by turning $\mathcal{P}(X)$ into a partially ordered single-valued algebra *(which I'll conflate with $\mathcal{P}(X)$ itself)*: for each $n$-ary $f\in\mathcal{F}$ we get a corresponding $\hat{f}: \mathcal{P}(X)^n\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(X)$ given by $$(S_1,...,S_n)\mapsto\{x\in X: \exists s_1\in S_1,...,s_n\in S_n(x\in f(s_1,...,s_n))\}.$$ As for the partial ordering, we use $\subseteq$ as expected.
- Now we look at the collection $\mathbb{A}_{X,\mathcal{F}}$ of sub-partially-ordered-algebras of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ which contain all the singletons. Containing the singletons amounts to "building off of $X$" in some sense; omitting a singleton would be an odd thing to do. Note that $\mathcal{P}(X)$ has lots of subalgebras which might be of more interest than the whole *(e.g. its smallest subalgebra containing all singletons, or the subalgebra consisting of the nonempty sets, or ...)*, so it's reasonable to consider this whole collection rather than fixating on $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

All the natural questions about multivalued algebra I can think of offhand can be translated directly to questions about either the $\mathbb{A}_{X,\mathcal{F}}$s or "canonical" elements of those collections (e.g. their smallest elements). As an outsider, this feels to me like good heuristic evidence that we're still solidly within the context of single-valued partially ordered algebras.